# iOS - add item end of table without refresh all data

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat height = scrollView.frame.size.height;

    CGFloat contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    CGFloat distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset;

    if(distanceFromBottom < height)
    {
        //END of table
    }
}
```

I can detect end of table when i came end of table i want to call new web service and add new N item how can i do this (I don't want to load all data again )

Comment: Look at the docs for `UITableView`. There are methods specific to inserting new rows/sections.

Comment: I add 15 item every refresh how can add specific insert i how to dynamic something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inserting

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation: (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

For deleting

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation: (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

But you have to make sure your datasource reflects the changes before hand.The cellForRowAtIndexPath method will be called for the specified indexPaths

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:inSection:`

```
[self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:myArrayOfIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Make sure your data source has the new data.  Your table view will pull its data from the usual methods. For what you are trying to do, you may want to call a method to load n more items, and before it returns, insert n rows to the end of the table view.

Comment: I got 6 array for one cell how can i use this method ? 6 time call this method ?

Comment: No, look at the method signature.  You pass an **NSArray** of the indexpaths you want to insert.